# Knockout JS: Increase a property value

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a semi-comprehensive KO setup. But so far I have only used KO to present the data.

Now I have a need to increase/decrease values on my model.

Here's my Model:

```
SharedItem: function (data) {
    var self = {};
    ...
    self.rating = ko.observable(data.Rating);
    ...
    return self;
}
```

And here's my View

```
ItemsViewModel: function (json) {
    var model = {};
    model.shareditems = ko.observableArray();

    var mappedSharedItems = [];
    var parsedData = $.parseJSON(json);

    $.each(parsedData, function (key, val) {
        var newSharedItems = new SharedItem(val);
        mappedSharedItems.push(newSharedItems);
    });

    //My function to vote
    model.voteUp = function(item) {
        item.rating += 1;
    }

    model.shareditems(mappedSharedItems);
    return model;
}
```

And my view is applied like any standard Knockout binding (response is my ajax response that I pass to the viewmodel):

```
var viewModel = ItemsViewModel(response);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#ItemListWrapper')[0]);
```

**But** I can't seem to figure out how to make my `voteUp` function increase the rating number.

**And important note:** The `rating` value is a string, from the server. But I guess I could be able to just use `parseInt` on it.

Can anyone point my in a direction on how to make this function increase a value of the model's property?

Thanks in advance

*Edit:* If you want to see the HTML where I call `voteUp` here it is:

```
<div class="Vote">
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.voteUp">+1</a>
</div>
```

*Edit 2:* My solution:

`item.rating(parseInt(item.rating()) + 1);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the observable syntax to do this:

```
model.voteUp = function(item) { item.rating(item.rating() + 1); }
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. And wrapping `parseInt()` around the string value, made it work. I think it's weird that the documentation doesn't cover much of the syntax... Or else I'm blind.

Comment: You're welcome. The documentation mentions that observables are implemented as functions. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't need `parseInt` function to increase/decrease value by 1, use `++` or `--` operand ( `item.rating++` OR `item.rating--` ).

Comment: Yes, I do, when the number is received in the form of a `string`.